# Please walk me through this code from ruby monk

Tags: ruby

```
def random_select(array, n)
  result = []
  n.times do
    # I do not fully understand how this line below works or why. Thank you 
    result.push array[rand(array.length)]
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: 1. `rand(array.length)` generates a random integer between zero and the size of `array` less one, so this will serve as a random index into the array.  2. `array[rand(array.length)]` extracts the element of `array` at offset `rand(array.length)`. 3. `push` appends that element to the end of the array `result`, which is initially empty. 4. This is repeated `n` times, at which time `result` will contain `n` elements. 5. The method `random_select` is to return `result`, so the last line of the method needs to be `result` (or `end; result`, but not `end result`).

Comment: Instead of `array[rand(array.length)]` it could use `array.sample`. Much easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably confused by this part:

```
n.times do
    result.push(array[rand(array.length)])
  end
```

`n.times` says it should loop n times.

`result.push` says to basically "push" or "put" something in the array. For example:

```
a = []
a.push(1)
p a #=> [1]
```

In `array[rand(array.length)]` , `rand(array.length)` will produce a random number as an index for the array. Why? `rand(n)` produces a number from 0 to n-1. `rand(5)` will produce either 0,1,2,3 or 4, for example.

Arrays use 0-based indexing, so if you have an array, say `a = ['x', 'y', 'z']`, to access 'x' you do `a[0]`, to access y you do `a[1]` and so on. If you want to access a random element from a, you do `a[rand(array.length)]`, because `a.length` in this case is 3, and `rand(3)` will produce a number that is either 0, 1 or 2. 0 is the smallest index and 2 is the largest index of our example array.

So suppose we call this method:

```
random_select([6,3,1,4], 2)
```

Try to see this code from the inside out. When the code reaches this part:

```
result.push(array[rand(array.length)])
```

it will first execute `array.length` which will produce 4. It will then execute `rand(array.length)` or `rand(4)` which will get a number between 0 and 3. Then, it will execute `array[rand(array.length)]` or `array(some_random_number_between_0_and_3)` which will get you a random element from the array. Finally, `result.push(all_of_that_code_inside_that_got_us_a_random_array_element)` will put the random element from the array in the method (in our example, it will be either 6, 3, 1 or 4) in the `results` array. Then it will repeat this same process once again (remember, we told it to go 2 times through the iteration).

Answer (score 0):

The code can be rewritten to be much simpler, using the block-form Array constructor:

```
def random_select(array, n)
  Array.new(n) {array.sample}
end
```

This creates a new array of size n and fills it with random samples from the array.

Note that the above solution, like your sample code, selects from the entire array each time which allows duplicate selections. If you don't want any duplicate selections, it's even simpler, since it is the default behavior of `Array#sample`:

```
def random_select(array, n)
  array.sample(n)
end
```